# Cauchy Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate this integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(x^2 + 1)}dx
$$
I am having a problem to solve this because of two poles when I solve it by integration first from $-R$ to $R$ and then along a semicircle in the upper half plane.

Comment: Use Residue theorem. Note that only $0$ and $i$ lie in the upper half plane.

Comment: You need to show your work, so that you can get direction towards the approach that'll get you to the solution.

Comment: And when i try to evalute ∫e∧iz/ z(z²⁺1)                                                               problem is that z=0 pole comes on boundry of our closed contour

Comment: $z=0$ should not be a problem because in fact $\text{Res} \bigl(\frac{\sin z}{z(z^2+1)}, 0\bigr)=0$

Comment: see z=0 is not inside the contour...its on boundry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your choice of the contour: $C$ is the upper half-plane and $\Gamma$ is the semicircular arc of radius $R$ (say).

$$\int_C \frac{\sin z}{z(z^2+1)}\mathrm dz=\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}\mathrm dx+\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\sin z}{z(z^2+1)}\mathrm dz$$

Now, use the fact that if $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ where $f$ and $g$ are analytic near $z_0$ and $h$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, then $\text{Res}(f(z), z_0) = \frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$. Note that $g$ is $\sin z$ and $h$ is $z(z^2+1)$. For the evaluation of the integral over the arc $\Gamma$, use the ML-inequality and you should be good to go.

Comment: First of all thanks, but sir we cant use ML inequalty because its unbounded

Comment: No the function is not unbounded. ML Inequality can be used. In fact, $\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin z}{z(z^2+1)}\mathrm dz=e^{-1}(e-1)\pi$.

Comment: can you show how you solve?

Comment: can you show how you solve?

Comment: i am new user, i dont know how to use this app

Comment: Follow these links to get the best out of Math SE and contributing to the community: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: i want to show you my paper work, in comment section i can only type but cant upload a picture, to upload a picture i have to answer my own question, i think no other way

Comment: Use MathJax reference for further actions on the Math SE site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88808/discussion-between-paras-khosla-and-sweety-tarika).

Comment: sure, still this qus is unsolved

Answer (score 2):

Let us avoid contour-hunting. The integrand function is even, hence it is enough to compute
$$ F(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx $$
(defined over $\text{Re}(a)>0$) at $a=1$. We may notice that
$$ (\mathcal{L} F)(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(s^2+x^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{\pi}{2s(s+1)} $$
hence
$$F(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-a}) $$
and
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx = \color{blue}{\pi(1-e^{-1})}.$$
There is no need to introduce a principal value: the $\text{sinc}$ function is continuous and bounded over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wowww...its good aproach

Comment: Sir,you directly write value of integration...when i try to solve by putting x² =t ...it become lengthy

Comment: is there any quick method for this integration?

Comment: @sweetytarika: quicker than the shown one, you mean? You may use Fourier transforms instead of Laplace transforms, it remains a four-liner or so.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that like @Jack D'Aurizio approach avoids contour integration altogether.

Let 
$$F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x(x^2 + 1)} \, dx = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x(x^2 + 1)} \, dx, \qquad a > 0.$$
We are required to find $F(1)$.

Using Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral sign we have
$$F'(a) = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (ax)}{x^2 + 1} \, dx,$$
and
$$F''(a) = - 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x \sin (ax)}{x^2 + 1} \, dx.$$
Observe that 
$$F''(a) - F(a) = -2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x} \, dx = -\pi.$$
Here the well-known result of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}, \qquad a > 0,$$
has been used.

One solving the differential equaltion $F''(a) - F(a) = -\pi$ we have
$$F(a) = C_1 e^a + C_2 e^{-a} + \pi.$$
The two unknown constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ can be found by noting that $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(0) = \pi$. Doing so one finds
$$F(a) = \pi(1 - e^{-a}).$$
Finally, setting $a = 1$ one has
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x(x^2 + 1)} \, dx = \pi(1 - e^{-1}),$$
as required.

Comment: in begining how you took F(a⁾=2 ,except this step every step is meaningfull

Comment: If you mean the factor of 2 appearing in front of the integral on the first line, that comes from the integrand being an even function between symmetric limits. Is this what you mean?

Comment: ohkk, got it..thanks